# Use Lucene to retrieve the line and column information for a match on a large input file?

Tags: java, lucene

I am indexing a large number of files and attempting to search over them based upon the file contents. I would like to be able to retrieve the line and column information for each match from the file.

Most of the examples that do this seem to rely on the file being imported completely to the index itself, but I am only using this to index:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new StringField("path", file.getPath(), Field.Store.YES));
Reader reader = new FileReader(file.getCanonicalPath());
doc.add(new TextField("contents", reader));
iwriter.addDocument(doc);
```

Is there a way to simply retrieve the position information from search hits on documents created in this way? Or is there a better way to create the documents that would make it easy?

At the moment, I am using Lucene 4.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to simply retrieve the position information from search
>   hits on documents created in this way?

As far as I know, No.
There is no automatic way since `contents` is not stored plus there is no position information of words in stored document. Stored document will have only one field - `path` and no other information so its not possible to retrieve it. I mean, leave aside positions of words, even `contents` wouldn't be available for retrieval.

> Or is there a better way to create the documents that would make it
>   easy?

Obviously, construct - `TextField(String name, Reader reader)` has this disadvantage of indexing only file contents and storing only `path` ( since you stored it explicitly ).

As far as I know, the way out is outside Lucene i.e. you retrieve `path` and keep indexed file then find that information from file itself i.e. row & column numbers. Obviously, this is not a practical solution.

I guess, practical solution would be the one that you already listed in your question i.e. when file content is also imported and document already have this information i.e. each document contains line number information plus you retrieve column information from `StringField` ( which is line content ) position of word.